# Packet Sniffer using winpcap missing some packets

Tags: c++, c, sockets, winpcap

I'm new to WinPcap and C/C++. I'm trying to make a packet sniffer. I've followed the example code from https://www.binarytides.com/code-packet-sniffer-c-winpcap.

The code looks like this:

```
/*
Simple Sniffer with winpcap , prints ethernet , ip , tcp , udp and icmp headers along with data dump in hex
*/

#include "stdio.h"
#include "winsock2.h"   //need winsock for inet_ntoa and ntohs methods

#define HAVE_REMOTE
#include "pcap.h"   //Winpcap :)

#pragma comment(lib , "ws2_32.lib") //For winsock
#pragma comment(lib , "wpcap.lib") //For winpcap

//some packet processing functions
void ProcessPacket (u_char* , int); //This will decide how to digest

void print_ethernet_header (u_char*);
void PrintIpHeader (u_char* , int);
void PrintIcmpPacket (u_char* , int);
void print_udp_packet (u_char* , int);
void PrintTcpPacket (u_char* , int);
void PrintData (u_char* , int);

// Set the packing to a 1 byte boundary
//#include "pshpack1.h"
//Ethernet Header
typedef struct ethernet_header
{
    UCHAR dest[6];
    UCHAR source[6];
    USHORT type;
}   ETHER_HDR , *PETHER_HDR , FAR * LPETHER_HDR , ETHERHeader;

//Ip header (v4)
typedef struct ip_hdr
{
    unsigned char ip_header_len:4; // 4-bit header length (in 32-bit words) normally=5 (Means 20 Bytes may be 24 also)
    unsigned char ip_version :4; // 4-bit IPv4 version
    unsigned char ip_tos; // IP type of service
    unsigned short ip_total_length; // Total length
    unsigned short ip_id; // Unique identifier

    unsigned char ip_frag_offset :5; // Fragment offset field

    unsigned char ip_more_fragment :1;
    unsigned char ip_dont_fragment :1;
    unsigned char ip_reserved_zero :1;

    unsigned char ip_frag_offset1; //fragment offset

    unsigned char ip_ttl; // Time to live
    unsigned char ip_protocol; // Protocol(TCP,UDP etc)
    unsigned short ip_checksum; // IP checksum
    unsigned int ip_srcaddr; // Source address
    unsigned int ip_destaddr; // Source address
} IPV4_HDR;

//UDP header
typedef struct udp_hdr
{
    unsigned short source_port; // Source port no.
    unsigned short dest_port; // Dest. port no.
    unsigned short udp_length; // Udp packet length
    unsigned short udp_checksum; // Udp checksum (optional)
} UDP_HDR;

// TCP header
typedef struct tcp_header
{
    unsigned short source_port; // source port
    unsigned short dest_port; // destination port
    unsigned int sequence; // sequence number - 32 bits
    unsigned int acknowledge; // acknowledgement number - 32 bits

    unsigned char ns :1; //Nonce Sum Flag Added in RFC 3540.
    unsigned char reserved_part1:3; //according to rfc
    unsigned char data_offset:4; /*The number of 32-bit words in the TCP header.
    This indicates where the data begins.
    The length of the TCP header is always a multiple
    of 32 bits.*/

    unsigned char fin :1; //Finish Flag
    unsigned char syn :1; //Synchronise Flag
    unsigned char rst :1; //Reset Flag
    unsigned char psh :1; //Push Flag
    unsigned char ack :1; //Acknowledgement Flag
    unsigned char urg :1; //Urgent Flag

    unsigned char ecn :1; //ECN-Echo Flag
    unsigned char cwr :1; //Congestion Window Reduced Flag

    ////////////////////////////////

    unsigned short window; // window
    unsigned short checksum; // checksum
    unsigned short urgent_pointer; // urgent pointer
} TCP_HDR;

typedef struct icmp_hdr
{
    BYTE type; // ICMP Error type
    BYTE code; // Type sub code
    USHORT checksum;
    USHORT id;
    USHORT seq;
} ICMP_HDR;
// Restore the byte boundary back to the previous value
//#include <poppack.h>

FILE *logfile;
int tcp=0,udp=0,icmp=0,others=0,igmp=0,total=0,i,j;
struct sockaddr_in source,dest;
char hex[2];

//Its free!
ETHER_HDR *ethhdr;
IPV4_HDR *iphdr;
TCP_HDR *tcpheader;
UDP_HDR *udpheader;
ICMP_HDR *icmpheader;
u_char *data;

int main()
{
    u_int i, res , inum ;
    u_char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE] , buffer[100];
    u_char *pkt_data;
    time_t seconds;
    struct tm tbreak;
    pcap_if_t *alldevs, *d;
    pcap_t *fp;
    struct pcap_pkthdr *header;

    fopen_s(&logfile , "log.txt" , "w");
    
    if(logfile == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Unable to create file.");
    }

    /* The user didn't provide a packet source: Retrieve the local device list */
    if (pcap_findalldevs_ex(PCAP_SRC_IF_STRING, NULL, &alldevs, errbuf) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in pcap_findalldevs_ex: %s\n", errbuf);
        return -1;
    }
    
    i = 0;
    /* Print the list */
    for(d=alldevs; d; d=d->next)
    {
        printf("%d. %s\n    ", ++i, d->name);

        if (d->description)
        {
            printf(" (%s)\n", d->description);
        }
        else
        {
            printf(" (No description available)\n");
        }
    }
        
    if (i==0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"No interfaces found! Exiting.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Enter the interface number you would like to sniff : ");
    scanf_s("%d" , &inum);

    
    /* Jump to the selected adapter */
    for (d=alldevs, i=0; i< inum-1 ;d=d->next, i++);
        
    /* Open the device */
    if ( (fp= pcap_open(d->name,
                        100 /*snaplen*/,
                        PCAP_OPENFLAG_PROMISCUOUS /*flags*/,
                        20 /*read timeout*/,
                        NULL /* remote authentication */,
                        errbuf)
                        ) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"\nError opening adapter\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //read packets in a loop :)
    while((res = pcap_next_ex( fp, &header, &pkt_data)) >= 0)
    {
        if(res == 0)
        {
            // Timeout elapsed
            continue;
        }
        seconds = header->ts.tv_sec;
        localtime_s( &tbreak , &seconds);
        strftime (buffer , 80 , "%d-%b-%Y %I:%M:%S %p" , &tbreak );
        //print pkt timestamp and pkt len
        //fprintf(logfile , "\nNext Packet : %ld:%ld (Packet Length : %ld bytes) " , header->ts.tv_sec, header->ts.tv_usec, header->len);
        fprintf(logfile , "\nNext Packet : %s.%ld (Packet Length : %ld bytes) " , buffer , header->ts.tv_usec, header->len);
        ProcessPacket(pkt_data , header->caplen);
    }
    
    if(res == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading the packets: %s\n" , pcap_geterr(fp) );
        return -1;
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void ProcessPacket(u_char* Buffer, int Size)
{
    //Ethernet header
    ethhdr = (ETHER_HDR *)Buffer;
    iphdr = (IPV4_HDR *)(Buffer + sizeof(ETHER_HDR));
    int z = ntohs(iphdr->ip_total_length);
    total+=z;
    
    //Ip packets
    if(ntohs(ethhdr->type) == 0x0800)
    {
        //ip header
        iphdr = (IPV4_HDR *)(Buffer + sizeof(ETHER_HDR));
     
        
        switch (iphdr->ip_protocol) //Check the Protocol and do accordingly...
        {
            case 1: //ICMP Protocol
            icmp++;
            PrintIcmpPacket(Buffer,Size);
            break;

            case 2: //IGMP Protocol
            igmp++;
            break;

            case 6: //TCP Protocol
            tcp++;
            PrintTcpPacket(Buffer,Size);
            break;

            case 17: //UDP Protocol
            udp++;
            print_udp_packet(Buffer,Size);
            break;

            default: //Some Other Protocol like ARP etc.
            others++;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    printf("TCP : %d UDP : %d ICMP : %d IGMP : %d Others : %d Total Size : %d\r" , tcp , udp , icmp , igmp , others , total);
}

/*
    Print the Ethernet header
*/
void print_ethernet_header (u_char* buffer )
{
    ETHER_HDR *eth = (ETHER_HDR *)buffer;
    
    fprintf(logfile,"\n");
    fprintf(logfile,"Ethernet Header\n");
    fprintf(logfile , " |-Destination Address : %.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X \n", eth->dest[0] , eth->dest[1] , eth->dest[2] , eth->dest[3] , eth->dest[4] , eth->dest[5] );
    fprintf(logfile , " |-Source Address      : %.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X \n", eth->source[0] , eth->source[1] , eth->source[2] , eth->source[3] , eth->source[4] , eth->source[5] );
    fprintf(logfile , " |-Protocol            : 0x%.4x \n" , ntohs(eth->type) );
}

/*
    Print the IP header for IP packets
*/
void PrintIpHeader (unsigned char* Buffer, int Size)
{
    int iphdrlen = 0;

    iphdr = (IPV4_HDR *)(Buffer + sizeof(ETHER_HDR));
    iphdrlen = iphdr->ip_header_len*4;

    memset(&source, 0, sizeof(source));
    source.sin_addr.s_addr = iphdr->ip_srcaddr;

    memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
    dest.sin_addr.s_addr = iphdr->ip_destaddr;

    print_ethernet_header(Buffer);

    fprintf(logfile,"\n");
    fprintf(logfile,"IP Header\n");
    fprintf(logfile," |-IP Version : %d\n",(unsigned int)iphdr->ip_version);
    fprintf(logfile," |-IP Header Length : %d DWORDS or %d Bytes\n",(unsigned int)iphdr->ip_header_len,((unsigned int)(iphdr->ip_header_len))*4);
    fprintf(logfile," |-Type Of Service : %d\n",(unsigned int)iphdr->ip_tos);
    fprintf(logfile," |-IP Total Length : %d Bytes(Size of Packet)\n",ntohs(iphdr->ip_total_length));
    fprintf(logfile," |-Identification : %d\n",ntohs(iphdr->ip_id));
    fprintf(logfile," |-Reserved ZERO Field : %d\n",(unsigned int)iphdr->ip_reserved_zero);
    fprintf(logfile," |-Dont Fragment Field : %d\n",(unsigned int)iphdr->ip_dont_fragment);
    fprintf(logfile," |-More Fragment Field : %d\n",(unsigned int)iphdr->ip_more_fragment);
    fprintf(logfile," |-TTL : %d\n",(unsigned int)iphdr->ip_ttl);
    fprintf(logfile," |-Protocol : %d\n",(unsigned int)iphdr->ip_protocol);
    fprintf(logfile," |-Checksum : %d\n",ntohs(iphdr->ip_checksum));
    fprintf(logfile," |-Source IP : %s\n",inet_ntoa(source.sin_addr));
    fprintf(logfile," |-Destination IP : %s\n",inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));
}

/*
    Print the TCP header for TCP packets
*/
void PrintTcpPacket(u_char* Buffer, int Size)
{
    unsigned short iphdrlen;
    int header_size = 0 , tcphdrlen , data_size;

    iphdr = (IPV4_HDR *)(Buffer + sizeof(ETHER_HDR));
    iphdrlen = iphdr->ip_header_len*4;

    tcpheader = (TCP_HDR*)( Buffer + iphdrlen + sizeof(ETHER_HDR) );
    tcphdrlen = tcpheader->data_offset*4;
    
    data = ( Buffer + sizeof(ETHER_HDR) + iphdrlen + tcphdrlen );
    data_size = (Size - sizeof(ETHER_HDR) - iphdrlen - tcphdrlen );

    fprintf(logfile,"\n\n***********************TCP Packet*************************\n");

    PrintIpHeader(Buffer,Size);

    fprintf(logfile,"\n");
    fprintf(logfile,"TCP Header\n");
    fprintf(logfile," |-Source Port : %u\n",ntohs(tcpheader->source_port));
    fprintf(logfile," |-Destination Port : %u\n",ntohs(tcpheader->dest_port));
    fprintf(logfile," |-Sequence Number : %u\n",ntohl(tcpheader->sequence));
    fprintf(logfile," |-Acknowledge Number : %u\n",ntohl(tcpheader->acknowledge));
    fprintf(logfile," |-Header Length : %d DWORDS or %d BYTES\n" , (unsigned int)tcpheader->data_offset,(unsigned int)tcpheader->data_offset*4);
    fprintf(logfile," |-CWR Flag : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcpheader->cwr);
    fprintf(logfile," |-ECN Flag : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcpheader->ecn);
    fprintf(logfile," |-Urgent Flag : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcpheader->urg);
    fprintf(logfile," |-Acknowledgement Flag : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcpheader->ack);
    fprintf(logfile," |-Push Flag : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcpheader->psh);
    fprintf(logfile," |-Reset Flag : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcpheader->rst);
    fprintf(logfile," |-Synchronise Flag : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcpheader->syn);
    fprintf(logfile," |-Finish Flag : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcpheader->fin);
    fprintf(logfile," |-Window : %d\n",ntohs(tcpheader->window));
    fprintf(logfile," |-Checksum : %d\n",ntohs(tcpheader->checksum));
    fprintf(logfile," |-Urgent Pointer : %d\n",tcpheader->urgent_pointer);
    fprintf(logfile,"\n");
    fprintf(logfile," DATA Dump ");
    fprintf(logfile,"\n");

    fprintf(logfile,"IP Header\n");
    PrintData( (u_char*)iphdr , iphdrlen);

    fprintf(logfile,"TCP Header\n");
    PrintData( (u_char*)tcpheader , tcphdrlen );

    fprintf(logfile,"Data Payload\n");
    PrintData( data , data_size );

    fprintf(logfile,"\n###########################################################\n");
}

/*
    Print the UDP header for UDP packets
*/
void print_udp_packet(u_char *Buffer,int Size)
{
    int iphdrlen = 0 , data_size = 0;

    iphdr = (IPV4_HDR *)(Buffer + sizeof(ETHER_HDR));
    iphdrlen = iphdr->ip_header_len*4;

    udpheader = (UDP_HDR*)( Buffer + iphdrlen + sizeof(ETHER_HDR) );
        
    data = ( Buffer + sizeof(ETHER_HDR) + iphdrlen + sizeof(UDP_HDR) );
    data_size = (Size - sizeof(ETHER_HDR) - iphdrlen - sizeof(UDP_HDR) );

    fprintf(logfile,"\n\n***********************UDP Packet*************************\n");

    PrintIpHeader(Buffer,Size);

    fprintf(logfile,"\nUDP Header\n");
    fprintf(logfile," |-Source Port : %d\n",ntohs(udpheader->source_port));
    fprintf(logfile," |-Destination Port : %d\n",ntohs(udpheader->dest_port));
    fprintf(logfile," |-UDP Length : %d\n",ntohs(udpheader->udp_length));
    fprintf(logfile," |-UDP Checksum : %d\n",ntohs(udpheader->udp_checksum));

    fprintf(logfile,"\n");
    
    fprintf(logfile,"IP Header\n");
    PrintData( (u_char*)iphdr , iphdrlen);

    fprintf(logfile,"UDP Header\n");
    PrintData((u_char*)udpheader , sizeof(UDP_HDR));

    fprintf(logfile,"Data Payload\n");
    PrintData(data ,data_size);

    fprintf(logfile,"\n###########################################################\n");
}

void PrintIcmpPacket(u_char* Buffer , int Size)
{
    int iphdrlen = 0 , icmphdrlen = 0 , data_size=0;

    iphdr = (IPV4_HDR *)(Buffer + sizeof(ETHER_HDR));
    iphdrlen = iphdr->ip_header_len*4;

    icmpheader = (ICMP_HDR*)( Buffer + iphdrlen + sizeof(ETHER_HDR) );
    
    data = ( Buffer + sizeof(ETHER_HDR) + iphdrlen + sizeof(ICMP_HDR) );
    data_size = (Size - sizeof(ETHER_HDR) - iphdrlen - sizeof(ICMP_HDR) );

    fprintf(logfile,"\n\n***********************ICMP Packet*************************\n");
    PrintIpHeader(Buffer,Size);

    fprintf(logfile,"\n");

    fprintf(logfile,"ICMP Header\n");
    fprintf(logfile," |-Type : %d",(unsigned int)(icmpheader->type));

    if((unsigned int)(icmpheader->type)==11) 
    {
        fprintf(logfile," (TTL Expired)\n");
    }
    else if((unsigned int)(icmpheader->type)==0) 
    {
        fprintf(logfile," (ICMP Echo Reply)\n");
    }

    fprintf(logfile," |-Code : %d\n",(unsigned int)(icmpheader->code));
    fprintf(logfile," |-Checksum : %d\n",ntohs(icmpheader->checksum));
    fprintf(logfile," |-ID : %d\n",ntohs(icmpheader->id));
    fprintf(logfile," |-Sequence : %d\n",ntohs(icmpheader->seq));
    fprintf(logfile,"\n");

    fprintf(logfile , "IP Header\n");
    PrintData( (u_char*)iphdr , iphdrlen);

    fprintf(logfile , "ICMP Header\n");
    PrintData( (u_char*)icmpheader , sizeof(ICMP_HDR) );

    fprintf(logfile , "Data Payload\n");
    PrintData(data , data_size);

    fprintf(logfile,"\n###########################################################\n");
}

/*
    Print the hex values of the data
*/
void PrintData (u_char* data , int Size)
{
    unsigned char a , line[17] , c;
    int j;
    
    //loop over each character and print
    for(i=0 ; i < Size ; i++)
    {
        c = data[i];
        
        //Print the hex value for every character , with a space
        fprintf(logfile," %.2x", (unsigned int) c);
        
        //Add the character to data line
        a = ( c >=32 && c <=128) ? (unsigned char) c : '.';
        
        line[i%16] = a;
        
        //if last character of a line , then print the line - 16 characters in 1 line
        if( (i!=0 && (i+1)%16==0) || i == Size - 1)
        {
            line[i%16 + 1] = '\0';
            
            //print a big gap of 10 characters between hex and characters
            fprintf(logfile ,"          ");
            
            //Print additional spaces for last lines which might be less than 16 characters in length
            for( j = strlen(line) ; j < 16; j++)
            {
                fprintf(logfile , "   ");
            }
            
            fprintf(logfile , "%s \n" , line);
        }
    }
    
    fprintf(logfile , "\n");
}
```

The program works fine when I run it. I tried to download some file and the total size displayed on the program is correct.

Then I tried to remove the logfile and change the `fprintf()` to `printf()`.

When I run my program again, it displays full log information on the console instead of the log file, but when I tried to download some file, and check the total size, it's less than the file size, so I think there are some packets missing.

I've tried to insert every packet into a database but some packets are also missing.

Is there any way to fix this, so that the program can display real-time packet sniffing without missing some packets?

Comment: Maybe printf is too slow

Comment: Calling pcap_stats at the end should tell you how many packets were ignored because your program was too slow to process them (that's `ps_drop`)

Comment: @user253751 is there any way to make my program faster?

Comment: Split the program to use 2 threads - (1) to capture packets and add them to a queue and (2) process the queue (logging etc).  Possibly investigate a non-blocking queue implementation.

Comment: don't print so much? but first, check the stats to see whether your program being slow is actually a problem

Comment: @user253751 i've tried using ps_drop, there're no packet drops, but some packets are missing.

Comment: @anonymous I didn't dig into the code, but my gut instinct is that you are not missing packets (which `ps_drop` appears to confirm) but you are just misinterpreting/ignoring the packets that you do get. How exactly are you determining that the "total size" is less-than the "file size"?

Comment: @RemyLebeau i get the total size from calculating all ip header total length. and the file size is just a file that i downloaded to check if the total size is correct. So it's like i run the program, then i downloaded a file with size 50mb. If my total size not more than 50mb then it means some packets gone missing.

Comment: @anonymous you didn't say HOW you are downloading the file. The first thing that comes to mind is maybe the transferred data is using compression to reduce bandwidth. Then the transferred size would be WAY smaller than the uncompressed size saved to file. The code shown is merely logging the raw transferred data, it is not attempting to interpret the application data in any way beyond the TCP/UDP layer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the file that i download is not compressed, i've tried downloaded a same video from youtube. When i'm using printf the total size become way smaller than the size of the video that i downloaded. but when i'm using fprintf to save the log into a .txt, the total size is just about the right amount

Comment: @anonymous First, as far as the packet data is concerned, there is *no difference* between using `printf` vs `fprintf`, so there is something else at play here. And second, are you accounting for the presence of SSL/TLS and HTTP protocol metadata on top of the video data? And yes, YouTube videos are compressed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry i'm still kinda new about this, but i think ip header full length is accounting the presence of SSL/TLS and HTTP protocol metadata. i just tried to download a video from youtube to check if my program proccess a right amount of packet data. for example when i downloaded a 30mb file. the total size when i use printf is just like 30k bytes, and when i use fprintf i can get more than 30mb for the total size. I think i shoud've used thread as Richard Critted said.

Comment: @anonymous Do you know what HTTP and SSL/TLS are, and how they work? If you are just looking for the file data, you have to keep drilling into the various data layers. `Ethernet > IP > TCP > SSL/TLS > HTTP > file data`. In any case, you are summing your `total` variable in the wrong place, and it includes the sizes of the IP and TCP headers, not just the transmitted application data. And you are not taking into account that the IPv4 and TCP headers are NOT fixed length, either.